# Объекты OpenGL в DLL

Tags: c++, opengl, dll

Так как у DLL своя память, то повлияет ли это на создание и использование объектов OpenGL?

Например, у меня есть DLL в котором создается `VBO`, `VAO` и `EBO` объекты. И я хочу использовать этот DLL файл в другом DLL файле для создания этих объектов. По логике, раз уж память у каждого DLL отдельная, то можно предположить что они не будут знать друг о друге, и OpenGL тоже не будет знать о той области памяти, где он нужен. И соответственно те объекты, которые были привязаны к своим идентификаторам будут работать только в той области памяти где эти объекты были созданы и привязаны.

Если это так, то что тут может помочь? Единственное что мне приходит в голову, это переписать DLL с `VBO`, `VAO` и `EBO` в хедер и использовать `inline` функции (По принципу метода, который мне подсказал @HolyBlackCat). Но может есть что-то получше?

EDIT:

```
class ROs : public HKCR::IROs {
public:
void init() override {
    HKCR::loadGLFunctions();
}

void create() override {
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &m_vaoID);
    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_vboID);
    glCreateBuffers(1, &m_eboID);
}

void pushToGPU(const std::vector<float>& vertices, const std::vector<index>& indices) override {
        glNamedBufferData(m_vboID, sizeof(float) * vertices.size(), &vertices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glNamedBufferData(m_eboID, sizeof(index) * indices.size(), &indices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Vertices position
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribFormat(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
        glVertexAttribBinding(0, 0);

        // Vertices texture coordinates
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribFormat(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2);
        glVertexAttribBinding(1, 0);

        // Vertices color
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribFormat(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * (2 + 2));
        glVertexAttribBinding(2, 0);
    }

    void unbind() override {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, 0);
    }

    private:
    void _deleteROs() override {
        delete this;
    }

    GLuint m_vboID;
    GLuint m_vaoID;
    GLuint m_eboID;
};

DLL_EXPORT HKCR::IROs* _createROs() {
    return new ROs;
}
```

Comment: *"Так как у DLL своя память"* Память своя есть у процесса, и с ней работают все загруженные в него dll.

Comment: `HKCR::loadGLFunctions();` - а тело этой функции где, в хедере или нет? Должно быть в хедере, иначе она будет каждый раз применяться к той dll где тело.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я его сделал так как ты мне сказал (в хедере, с inline, и в лямбде)

Comment: А `init()` зовете именно из DLL? Проще всего воткнуть `HKCR::loadGLFunctions()` перед всеми gl-ными вызовами, прямо в тех функциях, которые их делают.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так производительнее же вызывать его единожды. Разве нет?

Comment: И да я вызываю функцию `init` в том dll где его использую

Comment: Ну наверное да, но 1 - не сильно, и 2 - я подозреваю, что вы зовете ее где-то не там, а если делать это перед каждым использованием gl - не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Память у DLL общая. Единственная проблема, которая может быть - некоторые библиотеки-загрузчики GL требуют отдельной инициализации в каждой DLL, в которой их используют (у нас такое было, когда линковали GLAD статически - в каждой DLL нужно было звать `gladLoadGL` заново).

Comment: Ок. Тогда почему после создания этих объектов я не могу использовать `glDrawElements`? Появляется runtime исключение при использования этого макроса. И вот что там написано: "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FFA913BFAB3 (nvoglv64.dll) в Hyko_Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000008."

Comment: возможно проблема и не в том что я использую DLL, а в чем-то другом, но я сразу подумал на это

Comment: @LGL А какой библиотекой вы GL загружаете? Может правда нужно инициализировать заново в DLL.

Comment: @LGL Это у вас проблема XY. Вот про "нарушение прав доступа..." и надо было задавать вопрос.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я загружаю все тем же GLAD. И даже так, я загрузил функции OpenGL через тот метод, который ты мне подсказал в прошлом вопросе. Сейчас я обновлю вопрос и добавлю код с созданием объектов OpenGL

Comment: Я решил эту проблему (если это можно назвать решением). В функции `pushToGPU` неправильно инициализировались VAO, VBO и EBO, ну и я решил заменить содержимое этой функции на то которое я использовал раньше. Но этот способ уже старый как мне кажется, а я хотел использовать новые фишки OpenGL 4.5+. Но не суть. Теперь появилась другая проблема, тоже связанная с этим вопросом. Как мне использовать макрос `glGetUniformLocation`? Потому что он возвращает -1, хоть и имя uniform переменной правильное. Это точно не связано с тем что я создавал шейдеры и шейдерную программу в DLL?

Comment: @LGL Не связано. Он может возвращать -1 если эти переменные не используются в шейдере и выбрасываются оптимизатором.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну, она используется. Вот: `#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 aColor;

uniform mat4 VP;

out vec4 fragColor;
out vec2 textureCoord;

void main(){
 gl_Position = VP * vec4(aPos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
 fragColor = aColor;
}
`. А вот как я нахожу эту переменную и присваиваю ей значение: `const auto id = renderer->getPrimitivesShaderProgram();
 int location = glGetUniformLocation(id, "VP");
 glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj * view));`. `renderer` - эт DLL

Comment: @LGL Тогда хз, дебажить надо. Может https://renderdoc.org/ поможет.

Comment: И кстати, тут используется 2D графика, поэтому и 2D координаты. А также все объекты на сцене рендерятся как один для лучшей производительности

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, о, спасибо. Но можно же использовать такое же приложение, но от NVIDIA (у меня видеокарта от нее). Кстати, а есть ли отладчик для glsl шейдеров?

Comment: Про nvidia не понял, это универсальное. *"отладчик для glsl"* - я не видел, но особо не искал.